# Why do coronavirus cases graphs have a sinusoidal like shape?

Tags: statistics, coronavirus

Some screenshots from [a canadian website](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/info/2020/coronavirus-covid-19-pandemie-cas-carte-maladie-symptomes-propagation/index-en.html):

[image]
[image]

See this sinusoidal shape? Why is it there? Shouldn't it be a single curve?

My main guess is when cases are counted: is it possible that they are counted something like every monday or so? I can't believe the virus progression really has sinusoidal-shaped curve.

It is not an error in the website, since other sources seem to show the same thing: [worldometers](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/worldwide-graphs/), [nbc news](https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/coronavirus-numbers-new-cases-2020-n1157271), and many others

Comment: I think you mean SINE, not SINUS.  They're different words, with different origins. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sine#Etymology vs https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinus#Etymology

Comment: @jamesqf The page you liked says that sine is a "Doublet of sinus". Hence, they have the same origin. And since the OP has a non-English name, they probably speak on of the many languages where the function is indeed still called "sinus". For example, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinus#Noun_7

Comment: I did mean sine, thanks for the info. The sine function is labeled "sinus" in french.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a weekly cycle due to reporting disruptions over the weekend.

Use a 7-day moving average to get a better picture. Holidays and such can still be disruptive but the 7-day average solves most of it.

Comment: That's what happened in the UK. Most hospitals didn't report on Saturday / Sunday / Bank holidays, a small number did. The results published were based on the reports of the day before. So Saturday result = normal, Sunday result = low, Monday results = low (because little got reported on Sunday), Tuesday results = very high (most of Saturday / Sunday got reported on Monday), Wednesday results = slightly high (some hospitals didn't manage to report everything on Monday).

Comment: And then we had newspapers that reported every weekend how we are beating the virus because the numbers dropped, and every Tuesday how we were struck by total disaster because the numbers went up.